# Unable to use a directive inside another directive in Angular2

Tags: html, angularjs-directive, angular, angular2-directives

I have a html page where I'm loading my directive

```
<kms-dir1></kms-dir1>
```

in that component 'kmsdir1.html' is loaded i.e templateUrl, I have defined everything and working fine, now I have a requirement to use one more directive (let's say kmsdir2) in that kmsdir1.html

In that kmsdir1 component I have specified directives and tried but it's not loading

So currently I have defined another directive also in parent page and using input and output params and making its visibility hidden and show.

Is there any alternative???? i.e to load a directive inside one more directive

FYI: I didn't see any error in console. Page itself is not getting loaded (Blank)

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: I have a similar issue because I use a directive inside another directive. See the following question for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38974848/angular2-cli-directive-inside-another-directive-in-not-included-using-production.

Answer (score 1):

I would see two potential issues:

- You don't define directives into the `directives` property of the component where you want to use them
- The selectors you specify don't match any element in your component.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing "@Injectable()" to the component which I wanted to use it as directive.. and my bad I was use *ng-If instead *ngIf :-p

I understood whenever page is getting completely blank and no error in console then there is error in your angular syntax.